# $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ of logarithms over powers of x.

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {log_a(x)}{x^n} = L,$ $a>0$.

$L=0$ if $n>0$. $L \rightarrow \infty$ if $n\le 0.$

I am not sure whether the above statement is correct of not, but this is what I came up with:

For the first case, $n>0$, we have:

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {log_a(x)}{x^n} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\ln(x)}{x^n \cdot \ln(a)}$ is in an indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. So we can apply L'hospital's rule.

$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {\ln(x)}{x^n \cdot \ln(a)} =\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {1}{x \cdot n \cdot x^{n-1} \cdot \ln(a)} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {1}{n \cdot x^n \cdot \ln(a)} = 0.$

For the second case:

Let $t=-n$, so $t$ is never negative.

$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {log_a(x)}{x^n} = \lim_{x\to \infty} [x^t \cdot log_a(x)] \rightarrow \infty $

Is there anything wrong with what I wrote?

Comment: I guess it is right!

Comment: I would also say everything is correct.